# Kohana 3.2 - Routing questions

Tags: php, regex, routes, kohana, kohana-3

Firstly, Kohana's documentation is terrible, before people go "read the docs" I have read the docs and they don't seem to make much sense, even copying and pasting some of the code doesn't work for some things in the documentation.

With that in mind, I have a route like so:

```
//(enables the user to view the  profile / photos / blog, default is profile)
Route::set('profile', '<userid>(/<action>)(/)', array( // (/) for trailing slash
    "userid" => "[a-zA-Z0-9_]+",
    "action" => "(photos|blog)"
))->defaults(array(
    'controller' => 'profile',
    'action' => 'view'
))
```

This enables me to go `http://example.com/username` and be taken to the users profile, `http://example.com/username/photos` to be taken to view the users photos and `http://example.com/username/blog` to view the blog.

If somebody goes `http://example.com/username/something_else` I want it to default to the action `view` for the user specified in `<userid>` but I can't seem to find any way of doing this.

I could do it like this:

```
Route::set('profile', '<userid>(/<useraction>)(/)', array(
    "userid" => "[a-zA-Z0-9_]+",
    "useraction" => "(photos|blog)"
))->defaults(array(
    'controller' => 'profile',
    'action' => 'index'
))
```

then in the controller do this:

```
public function action_index(){
    $method = $this->request->param('useraction');
    if ($method && method_exists($this, "action_{$method}")) {
        $this->{"action_{$method}"}();
    } else if ($method) {
    // redirect to remove erroneous method from url
    } else {
        $this->action_view(); // view profile
    }
}
```

(it might be better in the `__construct()` function but you get the gist of it.)

I'd rather not do that though if there is a better method available (which there really should be)

I think the answer might be in the regex but the following does not work:

```
$profile_functions = "blog|images";
//(enables the user to view the images / blog)
Route::set('profile', '<id>/<action>(/)', array( 
            "id" => "[a-zA-Z0-9_]+",
            "action" => "($profile_functions)",
))->defaults(array(
    'controller' => 'profile'
));
Route::set('profile_2', '<id>(<useraction>)', array(
            "id" => "[a-zA-Z0-9_]+",
            "useraction" => "(?!({$profile_functions}))",
))->defaults(array(
    'controller' => 'profile',
    'action'     => 'view'
));
```

although it does match when nothing is after the ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would set up the route like this:

```
Route::set('profile', '<userid>(/<action>)(/)', array(
    "userid" => "[a-zA-Z0-9_]+",
    "action" => "[a-zA-Z]+"
))->defaults(array(
    'controller' => 'profile',
    'action' => 'index'
))
```

And then in the controllers before() method:

```
if(!in_array($this->request->_action, array('photos', 'blog', 'index')){
    $this->request->_action = 'view';
}
```

Or somethig similiar, just validate the action in the controller...

EDIT:

This could also work:

```
if(!is_callable(array($this, 'action_' . $this->request->_action))){
    $this->request->_action = 'view';
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. Return to what?

Comment: instead of using array, but ignore me... `in_array("action_{$request->_action}", get_class_methods($this))`